# Is it possible to give timesheet access to portal users in Odoo?

Tags: odoo-17

I have created a portal user in odoo 17 and login from that user. I have selected a project and a task in it. Now on Time sheets tab, i want to add a line but its not permitted to portal user. Its allow internal user only.

`<tree string="Timesheet Activities" default_order="date" no_open="1" create="false" delete="0">`

I have tried to by changing create="false" to create="true" for tree view but its not working. Please guide me how i can allow portal user to add time-sheets.

Answer (score 0):

> In Odoo, portal users are primarily designed for website interaction,
> purchases, and document visibility related to sales or purchases.
>
> it's important to note that portal users do have certain limitations,
> and accessing the project and time-sheet modules directly from the
> back-end is not within their scope.